# Valgrind reports "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" on every program

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I'm working through "Learn C the Hardway" and using valgrind to debug my programs, but it keeps giving me the same error, even on programs I know for a fact are correct. I'm running ubuntu on a VMware virtual machine which I thought might be the problem but it works fine on another Windows computer using the same setup. I originally built valgrind from sratch per the book but removed it and used sudo-apt get install to see if it made a difference but still same error.

Here's the error on a simple hello world program and I get the exact same results on every C program I run.

```
bizarro@ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Programming/C/TheHardWay/Exercises$ valgrind ./ex1
==8625== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8625== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8625== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8625== Command: ./ex1
==8625== 
==8625== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8625==    at 0x4019B04: index (strchr.S:77)
==8625==    by 0x4007DED: expand_dynamic_string_token (dl-load.c:425)
==8625==    by 0x4008D71: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2538)
==8625==    by 0x40014BD: map_doit (rtld.c:627)
==8625==    by 0x400FFF3: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:187)
==8625==    by 0x4000B2E: do_preload (rtld.c:816)
==8625==    by 0x400446C: dl_main (rtld.c:1633)
==8625==    by 0x4017564: _dl_sysdep_start (dl-sysdep.c:249)
==8625==    by 0x4004CF7: _dl_start (rtld.c:332)
==8625==    by 0x40012D7: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so)
==8625== 
Hello world.
This is a the print function
It prints things and needs a semi colon at the end
Which im not used to. Python has made me sloppy  
I miss Python already
==8625== 
==8625== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8625==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8625==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==8625== 
==8625== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8625== 
==8625== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8625== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==8625== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

edit*

Here is the code but like I said it gives this message independent of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    puts("This is a the print function");
    puts("It prints things and needs a semi colon at the end");
    puts("Which im not used to. Python has made me sloppy");
    puts("I miss Python already");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. The output from valgrind is useless without context.

Comment: It is possible that Valgrind is identifying a problem in your libc (to which every C program is linked). That would explain what you are seeing. We will confirm after you post one example of C program that causes the Valgrind message.

Comment: I see this _exact_ error in the redhad bugs reports(https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=801841) and debian (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=583856) says it's an error in glibc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though Valgrind is identifying a potential issue within the C runtime. This isn't something you need to worry about, so I'd recommend that you [create a suppressions file](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) to ignore this particular warning.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds right. I don't get any errors running your code with valgrind --leak-check=full.